# Is there a way to actually save a mySQL database to Github?

Tags: mysql, database, git, github

I've been looking around and all I can find is people managing db scripts using github.  So they aren't storing the databases, but a list of all commands performed on a database which is then use to sync up two separate databases.

I'm managing my MySQL database using a number of php pages.  Is there some way that I can actually store a real database on github along with my website, such that no matter which box I'm working from I'll be using the same database?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Why not?! You can commit the database directory to git if you want to. Programmers usually share only code on Git, not data.

Anyway, check this link http://www.mkyong.com/mysql/where-does-mysql-stored-the-data-in-my-harddisk/ to get `datadir` path on your system. Go there and you can find folders for every database that exists on mySQL. Commit the necessary `.frm` file to git.

Comment: Note that GitHub has a [disk quota](https://help.github.com/articles/what-is-my-disk-quota/) currently set at 1GB per repository and 100MB per file.  Depending on what's in your database you might reach one of those limits pretty quickly.

Comment: Can the website be hosted on github, and actually access the database stored on github?

Comment: Nope. Highly unlikely. Github is a version controlling software basically designed to facilitate code reuse and revisions. You need to use a database server unless someone invents a fancy tool to read database files directly off of github.

Answer (score 1):

You can also create a git hook which can automatically dump the database.

I use this git hook `https://github.com/BlurryFlurry/switchdbwhencheckout` for switching the database when I switching branches.